# Firebase + Auth0 security model

Tags: security, firebase, auth0

So I'm working on an app that implements these two technologies, I have users able to login with the most common social media outlets and generate and access content. The question I have is, if a user has the app, they can in theory get to the data. How do I build a security model around these technologies that allows me to block a user from getting to the content?

```
{ "rules": { ".read": "auth !=null", ".write": "auth !=null" } }
```

Comment: Firebase's built-int login and/or Auth0 handle authentication: identifying a user. To then allow/disallow access to the data, you'd use Firebase's security rules. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/

Comment: There has to be an easier way then to create a rule for each user i want to block. I need security on a very granular level. If I have Jane Doe, John Doe and Jason Doe, I need to block access for Jane, but allow John and Jason. I'm looking through the auth0 documentation, it feels like it should be there...

Comment: To secure data in Firebase, you add security rules. If you've written those and feel that they are convoluted, show you security rules and a sample of your data structure. Without those, we can't help, except pointing you to the documentation.

Comment: I'm not trying to secure the data Frank, It's an all or nothing, they either can authenticate or they can't

Comment: That rule allows authenticated users full read and write access to the data. Non-authenticated users won't have access. Note that it really helps if you show this information *inside* your question (there is an edit link right under it) and show your data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth0 can both authenticate users and also provide authorization/access control through its Rules feature.
Documentation link for Rules explains how this works:   https://auth0.com/docs/rules

From the Auth0 dashboard you can access several sample rules.  (Auth0 Dashboard -> Rules -> +New Rule).  The "Whitelist" sample rule controls access for specific users.  There are other sample rules for access control based on roles, day of week, etc. You can start from the samples and modify them to meet your exact needs and you can leverage user profile attributes in Rule logic as well.